# 'missing operator at _@_' when adding xdata to RBC graph element

Tags: list, graph, tcl, operator-keyword

I'm currently learning how to use the rbc library right now. I have some hardware that is returning two lists: one is time and the other is voltage. Here is the line of tcl where I try and create the element:

```
    $myGraph element create "CH${channel}:${polarity}" -xdata [list [lindex [lindex $myWaveform 2] 0]] -ydata [list [lindex [lindex $myWaveform 2] 1]]
```

Note: I use `lindex` twice because it is a list of lists and I need to index into the first list to get to my data.

Now, when executing this code, I get the following error message:

```
missing operator at _@_
in expression "1.9e-8 _@_1.902e-8 1.904e-8 1.90..."
```

Now, I'd post my list here except it's HUGE (>4000 elements). But basically what you see in the snippet of the error is the format of the list:

```
"1.9e-8 1.902e-8 1.904e-8 1.90..."
```

Now, I know for a fact that the data being passed in is of type list and is what I'm looking for, as I have done a `llength` function on it, and it is a list of 4000 elements. I'm not sure where it's getting the 'operator' from, as there is nothing in the list at the position '*@*' occupies in the error. What could possibly be wrong with my list?

EDIT: When I manually do this process through the console, it works. Why wouldn't it work in the code?

Comment: The list is most likely passed to the `expr` command at some point: it gives that error message f.i. when it gets such a list of values. Also, you don't really need `[lindex [lindex $myWaveform 2] 0]`: `[lindex $myWaveform 2 0]` will do.

Comment: How would I format my list so that it does not throw this error? I cannot rewrite the rbc library to not user `expr`.

Comment: If your data goes through `expr` it must consist of a single expression, i.e. a value or a number of operands connected by operators. Are you sure that the command expects a list of values? (I don't know anything about rbc.)

Comment: I posted an explanation in my answer to my own question below. Although it was expecting a list of >1 values, it was only getting a list of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. For some reason, the function I was using to acquire the data put it into a list of size 1, where the first element was my actual data list, of size 4000:

```
{{"1.9e-8 1.902e-8 1.904e-8 1.90..."}}
```

Because it was trying to iterate over this list of size 1, it was running into errors.

Comment: That makes sense: it passes every element in the list it gets to `expr`, and if every value it gets is crammed into one element, that's what gets passed. Maybe you were calling `list` around the function that provides the data? In your first example you call `list` around the values for `-xdata` and `-ydata`, which looks suspect.

Comment: I didn't see that earlier... what you've got there is basically a list of one element consisting of a list of one element consisting of a list of values.

Comment: @PeterLewerin I suppose this makes sense. The library I am using to get data allows multiple data sets to be captured, but I am only using it for one. So if I had >1 data set, the length of the "top" list would be >1